# WGET - HTTPS vs HTTP = HTTPS Slower

Tags: linux, ssl, curl, raspberry-pi, wget

I am trying to do some tests using the wget and I noticed that HTTPS pages take significant to load in wget than http for the same server.
This does not seem related to any network difference. Before the name resolution wget takes about 5 extra seconds.
Can anyone help? How can I overcome this? I was looking to using wget with -p and -H options to evaluate network performance when I noticed this.

```
xbian@xbian ~ $ wget -V
GNU Wget 1.13.4 built on linux-gnueabihf.

+digest +https +ipv6 +iri +large-file +nls -ntlm +opie +ssl/gnutls

Wgetrc:
    /etc/wgetrc (system)
Locale: /usr/share/locale
Compile: gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DSYSTEM_WGETRC="/etc/wgetrc"
    -DLOCALEDIR="/usr/share/locale" -I. -I../lib -I../lib
    -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Iyes/include -g -O2 -fstack-protector
    --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security
    -DNO_SSLv2 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g -Wall
Link: gcc -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat
    -Werror=format-security -DNO_SSLv2 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g -Wall
    -Wl,-z,relro -Lyes/lib -lgnutls -lgcrypt -lgpg-error -lz -lidn -lrt
    ftp-opie.o gnutls.o ../lib/libgnu.a

Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later
<http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Originally written by Hrvoje Niksic <hniksic@xemacs.org>.
Please send bug reports and questions to <bug-wget@gnu.org>.
xbian@xbian ~ $ time wget -d -v --no-check-certificate --delete-after -4 http://www.google.pt 2>&1  | awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; fflush(); }'
2015-02-07 01:10:57 Setting --verbose (verbose) to 1
2015-02-07 01:10:57 Setting --check-certificate (checkcertificate) to 0
2015-02-07 01:10:57 Setting --delete-after (deleteafter) to 1
2015-02-07 01:10:57 Setting --inet4-only (inet4only) to 1
2015-02-07 01:10:57 DEBUG output created by Wget 1.13.4 on linux-gnueabihf.
2015-02-07 01:10:57
2015-02-07 01:10:57 URI encoding = `UTF-8'
2015-02-07 01:10:57 --2015-02-07 01:10:57--  http://www.google.pt/
2015-02-07 01:10:57 Resolving www.google.pt (www.google.pt)... 213.30.5.52, 213.30.5.24, 213.30.5.18, ...
2015-02-07 01:10:57 Caching www.google.pt => 213.30.5.52 213.30.5.24 213.30.5.18 213.30.5.25 213.30.5.59 213.30.5.31 213.30.5.45 213.30.5.46 213.30.5.39 213.30.5.53 213.30.5.32 213.30.5.38
2015-02-07 01:10:57 Connecting to www.google.pt (www.google.pt)|213.30.5.52|:80... connected.
2015-02-07 01:10:57 Created socket 3.
2015-02-07 01:10:57 Releasing 0x003b8040 (new refcount 1).
2015-02-07 01:10:57
2015-02-07 01:10:57 ---request begin---
2015-02-07 01:10:57 GET / HTTP/1.1
2015-02-07 01:10:57 User-Agent: Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnueabihf)
2015-02-07 01:10:57 Accept: */*
2015-02-07 01:10:57 Host: www.google.pt
2015-02-07 01:10:57 Connection: Keep-Alive
2015-02-07 01:10:57
2015-02-07 01:10:57 ---request end---
2015-02-07 01:10:58 HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
2015-02-07 01:10:58 ---response begin---
2015-02-07 01:10:58 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
2015-02-07 01:10:58 Date: Sat, 07 Feb 2015 01:10:58 GMT
2015-02-07 01:10:58 Expires: -1
2015-02-07 01:10:58 Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
2015-02-07 01:10:58 Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
2015-02-07 01:10:58 Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=98608883e4031983:FF=0:TM=1423271458:LM=1423271458:S=BnwaLDxFbjCUyPnF; expires=Mon, 06-Feb-2017 01:10:58 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.pt
2015-02-07 01:10:58 Set-Cookie: NID=67=AkXpY2nJPDDcH7xKJkslxdCtflnhOZJiNwZdu4YBAIc2FnjIZIAYHzFuln5boxiOHq1WWBdbcTnLXwPqOrfxOxkLXtO2U5UAVBCU0nVcgyC61_YLZLXGR0Fmdi9M_fIp; expires=Sun, 09-Aug-2015 01:10:58 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.pt; HttpOnly
2015-02-07 01:10:58 P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
2015-02-07 01:10:58 Server: gws
2015-02-07 01:10:58 X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
2015-02-07 01:10:58 X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
2015-02-07 01:10:58 Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic,p=0.02
2015-02-07 01:10:58 Accept-Ranges: none
2015-02-07 01:10:58 Vary: Accept-Encoding
2015-02-07 01:10:58 Transfer-Encoding: chunked
2015-02-07 01:10:58
2015-02-07 01:10:58 ---response end---
2015-02-07 01:10:58 200 OK
2015-02-07 01:10:58 cdm: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
2015-02-07 01:10:58 Stored cookie google.pt -1 (ANY) / <permanent> <insecure> [expiry 2017-02-06 01:10:58] PREF ID=98608883e4031983:FF=0:TM=1423271458:LM=1423271458:S=BnwaLDxFbjCUyPnF
2015-02-07 01:10:58 cdm: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
2015-02-07 01:10:58 Stored cookie google.pt -1 (ANY) / <permanent> <insecure> [expiry 2015-08-09 02:10:58] NID 67=AkXpY2nJPDDcH7xKJkslxdCtflnhOZJiNwZdu4YBAIc2FnjIZIAYHzFuln5boxiOHq1WWBdbcTnLXwPqOrfxOxkLXtO2U5UAVBCU0nVcgyC61_YLZLXGR0Fmdi9M_fIp
2015-02-07 01:10:58 Registered socket 3 for persistent reuse.
2015-02-07 01:10:58 URI content encoding = `ISO-8859-1'
2015-02-07 01:10:58 Length: unspecified [text/html]
2015-02-07 01:10:58 Saving to: `index.html'
2015-02-07 01:10:58
2015-02-07 01:10:58      0K .......... .......                                     17.6M=0.001s
2015-02-07 01:10:58
2015-02-07 01:10:58 2015-02-07 01:10:58 (17.6 MB/s) - `index.html' saved [18301]
2015-02-07 01:10:58
2015-02-07 01:10:58 Removing file due to --delete-after in main():
2015-02-07 01:10:58 Removing index.html.

real    0m0.350s
user    0m0.038s
sys     0m0.027s
xbian@xbian ~ $ time wget -d -v --no-check-certificate --delete-after -4 https://www.google.pt 2>&1  | awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; fflush(); }'
2015-02-07 01:11:01 Setting --verbose (verbose) to 1
2015-02-07 01:11:01 Setting --check-certificate (checkcertificate) to 0
2015-02-07 01:11:01 Setting --delete-after (deleteafter) to 1
2015-02-07 01:11:01 Setting --inet4-only (inet4only) to 1
2015-02-07 01:11:01 DEBUG output created by Wget 1.13.4 on linux-gnueabihf.
2015-02-07 01:11:01
2015-02-07 01:11:01 URI encoding = `UTF-8'
2015-02-07 01:11:01 --2015-02-07 01:11:01--  https://www.google.pt/
2015-02-07 01:11:06 Resolving www.google.pt (www.google.pt)... 213.30.5.25, 213.30.5.53, 213.30.5.38, ...
2015-02-07 01:11:06 Caching www.google.pt => 213.30.5.25 213.30.5.53 213.30.5.38 213.30.5.32 213.30.5.24 213.30.5.46 213.30.5.39 213.30.5.18 213.30.5.52 213.30.5.31 213.30.5.59 213.30.5.45
2015-02-07 01:11:06 Connecting to www.google.pt (www.google.pt)|213.30.5.25|:443... connected.
2015-02-07 01:11:06 Created socket 4.
2015-02-07 01:11:06 Releasing 0x00b53d48 (new refcount 1).
2015-02-07 01:11:06
2015-02-07 01:11:06 ---request begin---
2015-02-07 01:11:06 GET / HTTP/1.1
2015-02-07 01:11:06 User-Agent: Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnueabihf)
2015-02-07 01:11:06 Accept: */*
2015-02-07 01:11:06 Host: www.google.pt
2015-02-07 01:11:06 Connection: Keep-Alive
2015-02-07 01:11:06
2015-02-07 01:11:06 ---request end---
2015-02-07 01:11:06 HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
2015-02-07 01:11:06 ---response begin---
2015-02-07 01:11:06 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
2015-02-07 01:11:06 Date: Sat, 07 Feb 2015 01:11:06 GMT
2015-02-07 01:11:06 Expires: -1
2015-02-07 01:11:06 Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
2015-02-07 01:11:06 Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
2015-02-07 01:11:06 Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=579b1dd2360c9122:FF=0:TM=1423271466:LM=1423271466:S=9zOSotidcZWjJfXX; expires=Mon, 06-Feb-2017 01:11:06 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.pt
2015-02-07 01:11:06 Set-Cookie: NID=67=Jetj6llJijt09db9ekqGS6cBo3DE0CDqfQkp9Sh8xtLyYnNGU5zHoMED0whNkToP_w6mk6-oLTSRVdYIDekUEZH02oBYQPQhHmhpQzENI08zGNg9Jxn4EkXTIVApLCAG; expires=Sun, 09-Aug-2015 01:11:06 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.pt; HttpOnly
2015-02-07 01:11:06 P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
2015-02-07 01:11:06 Server: gws
2015-02-07 01:11:06 X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
2015-02-07 01:11:06 X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
2015-02-07 01:11:06 Accept-Ranges: none
2015-02-07 01:11:06 Vary: Accept-Encoding
2015-02-07 01:11:06 Transfer-Encoding: chunked
2015-02-07 01:11:06
2015-02-07 01:11:06 ---response end---
2015-02-07 01:11:06 200 OK
2015-02-07 01:11:06 cdm: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
2015-02-07 01:11:06 Stored cookie google.pt -1 (ANY) / <permanent> <insecure> [expiry 2017-02-06 01:11:06] PREF ID=579b1dd2360c9122:FF=0:TM=1423271466:LM=1423271466:S=9zOSotidcZWjJfXX
2015-02-07 01:11:06 cdm: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
2015-02-07 01:11:06 Stored cookie google.pt -1 (ANY) / <permanent> <insecure> [expiry 2015-08-09 02:11:06] NID 67=Jetj6llJijt09db9ekqGS6cBo3DE0CDqfQkp9Sh8xtLyYnNGU5zHoMED0whNkToP_w6mk6-oLTSRVdYIDekUEZH02oBYQPQhHmhpQzENI08zGNg9Jxn4EkXTIVApLCAG
2015-02-07 01:11:06 Registered socket 4 for persistent reuse.
2015-02-07 01:11:06 URI content encoding = `ISO-8859-1'
2015-02-07 01:11:06 Length: unspecified [text/html]
2015-02-07 01:11:06 Saving to: `index.html'
2015-02-07 01:11:06
2015-02-07 01:11:06      0K .......... .......                                      670K=0.03s
2015-02-07 01:11:06
2015-02-07 01:11:06 2015-02-07 01:11:06 (670 KB/s) - `index.html' saved [18319]
2015-02-07 01:11:06
2015-02-07 01:11:06 Removing file due to --delete-after in main():
2015-02-07 01:11:06 Removing index.html.

real    0m5.371s
user    0m4.083s
sys     0m0.280s
```

In curl, the difference does not seem that big...

```
xbian@xbian ~ $ curl -V
curl 7.26.0 (arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf) libcurl/7.26.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1e zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.25 libssh2/1.4.2 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: Debug GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP
xbian@xbian ~ $ time curl -s http:///www.google.pt > /dev/null

real    0m0.140s
user    0m0.056s
sys     0m0.034s
xbian@xbian ~ $ time curl -s https:///www.google.pt > /dev/null

real    0m0.294s
user    0m0.060s
sys     0m0.031s
```

Comment: Why not just use curl?

Comment: Because I actually want to use the -p and -H options. I do not thing curl supports this.

Comment: After some tests and discussion with wget developers, I came to the conclusion that this was due to the gnutls library. If wget is compiled with openssl instead, the behaviour is much more like curl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tests and discussion with wget developers, I came to the conclusion that this was due to the gnutls library. If wget is compiled with openssl instead, the behaviour is much more like curl.

Answer (score 0):

There is some overhead related to setting up an SSL/TSL because a session key has to be established, however this tends to be negligible, so I doubt that it would the real reason, but one never knows.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I overcome this?

You can't.

The difference between HTTP and HTTPS is that the latter is using SSL/TLS to secure the connection.  SSL/TLS has significant overheads:

- At start up, the client and server exchange certificates, etcetera to so that (at least) the client can verify that the server is not an imposter.

  The start up negotiation entails a number of client <-> server message exchanges.  If the TCP/IP level connection has appreciable latency, this will manifest as a noticeable delay.
- Once the connection has been established, data that goes over the connection is encrypted on send and decrypted on receive.

---

I don't think there is any practical alternative to HTTPS is you want to talk securely to a regular, current generation web server.  I don't think it changes with "next generation" HTTP; i.e. HTTP/2.

The only thing you can do to speed things up (HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2) is to reuse a "persistent connection" for multiple GETs.  The SSL/TLS negotiation only occurs when the connection is established.  However, persistent connections don't help in the "single shot" use-case; e.g. when you use `wget` or `curl` to fetch one file.

Comment: Actually, even with HTTP/1.1, you can use a persistent connection and reuse the same connection for multiple requests over HTTPS. The SSL/TLS negotiation needs to occur only when creating a new connection.

Comment: @damir - Thanks.  (Actually, I knew that ... :-) )

Comment: But it seems like the 5 second overhead happens before the connection even starts (before the name resolution actually)... Does this make sense?

Comment: Possibly.  It could actually be DNS resolution ... combined with a DNS-based load balancer.

Comment: It definitely is because of DNS resolution. As for @husvar's query about the overhead occurring before the name resolution takes place, please take a look at the comment I just left on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I overcome this?

`this`, is not an issue with GNU Wget. I tried running your commands:

```
$ time wget -d -v --no-check-certificate --delete-after -4 http://www.google.pt 2>&1  | awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; fflush(); }'
$ time wget -d -v --no-check-certificate --delete-after -4 https://www.google.pt 2>&1  | awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; fflush(); }'
```

And ran them about 10 times each. The end result? The difference in time was minor, as is expected due to the SSL/TSL negotiation protocol. This aligns well with my expectations of GNU Wget's behaviour. So why did you see such a large difference?

Let's look at your output for the `https` version:

```
2015-02-07 01:11:01 Setting --verbose (verbose) to 1
2015-02-07 01:11:01 Setting --check-certificate (checkcertificate) to 0
2015-02-07 01:11:01 Setting --delete-after (deleteafter) to 1
2015-02-07 01:11:01 Setting --inet4-only (inet4only) to 1
2015-02-07 01:11:01 DEBUG output created by Wget 1.13.4 on linux-gnueabihf.
2015-02-07 01:11:01
2015-02-07 01:11:01 URI encoding = `UTF-8'
2015-02-07 01:11:01 --2015-02-07 01:11:01--  https://www.google.pt/
2015-02-07 01:11:06 Resolving www.google.pt (www.google.pt)... 213.30.5.25, 213.30.5.53, 213.30.5.38, ...
2015-02-07 01:11:06 Caching www.google.pt => 213.30.5.25 213.30.5.53 213.30.5.38 213.30.5.32 213.30.5.24 213.30.5.46 213.30.5.39 213.30.5.18 213.30.5.52 213.30.5.31 213.30.5.59 213.30.5.45
2015-02-07 01:11:06 Connecting to www.google.pt (www.google.pt)|213.30.5.25|:443... connected.
2015-02-07 01:11:06 Created socket 4.
2015-02-07 01:11:06 Releasing 0x00b53d48 (new refcount 1).
2015-02-07 01:11:06
2015-02-07 01:11:06 ---request begin---
2015-02-07 01:11:06 GET / HTTP/1.1
2015-02-07 01:11:06 User-Agent: Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnueabihf)
2015-02-07 01:11:06 Accept: */*
2015-02-07 01:11:06 Host: www.google.pt
2015-02-07 01:11:06 Connection: Keep-Alive
2015-02-07 01:11:06
2015-02-07 01:11:06 ---request end---
```

I have only considered the output till the time Wget sends its first request. At this point, the SSL/TSL negotiation which everyone claims caused the dramatic rise in time, hasn't even begun. Yet, if you notice closely, the time taken is > 5s!

Hence, this behaviour that you notice is definitely not caused by the overhead of using HTTPS. So, what is it then? Again, look close at the output. Between which lines did the maximum time elapse?

```
2015-02-07 01:11:01 --2015-02-07 01:11:01--  https://www.google.pt/
2015-02-07 01:11:06 Resolving www.google.pt (www.google.pt)... 213.30.5.25, 213.30.5.53, 213.30.5.38, ...
```

That means it took Wget ~5 seconds to resolve the IP address from the domain names. However, DNS resolution is not something that Wget handles at all. Wget requests the system for getting the IP address. This can be seen in the file `host.c:329`:

```
static void
gethostbyname_with_timeout_callback (void *arg)
{
  struct ghbnwt_context *ctx = (struct ghbnwt_context *)arg;
  ctx->hptr = gethostbyname (ctx->host_name);
}
```

Hence, what really happened in your case was that your system took some extra time to resolve the hostname. This can happen for a wide variety of reasons. However, instead of running your test multiple times you fell for Hasty Generalization and simply assumed that Wget does HTTPS very slowly.

Comment: The problem is that the 5 seconds were spent until the "Resolving...." line appeared (not while resolving). This delay is 5 seconds always. It seems to be related to soem task before the name resolution...

Comment: Sure. That is caused by compiler and library optimizations. Modern compilers would optimize the code and shift the print statements slightly for a performance boost. On top of it, printf() is known to buffer the output for an entire line. Since the IP addresses are printed on the same line as "Resolving...", it is entirely possible that you do not see the output because it hasn't been flushed to stdout. (stderr to be precise)

Comment: I am going to add this to the hosts file to make sure. But this happens only for https and there is nothing different in name resoulution between https and http.

Comment: Does it happen everytime? Can you repeat the test and reliably say that it takes 5 seconds to complete the dns resolution on https?

Comment: I just tested with the name in the hosts file and the 5 sec extra delay still happens...

Comment: Okay, let's attempt to debug this. Could you please pass both the URLs to `dig` and see how much time it takes to resolve them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70474/discussion-between-darnir-and-husvar).

Answer (score 0):

Your machine is probably trying an IPv6 DNS lookup and failing because it is not configured correctly. It falls back to IPv4 after a timeout and then the connection succeeds. If this is the problem, you'll need to either fix your IPv6 configuration or disable IPv6 completely.

To test this theory, use "ping6" to try to ping the host you're trying to connect to. My guess is that "ping6" will fail while "ping" will succeed.

## How to Test:

```
greg@mycomputer:~$ ping6 www.google.pt
PING www.google.pt(ord30s26-in-x03.1e100.net) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from ord30s26-in-x03.1e100.net: icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=19.5 ms
64 bytes from ord30s26-in-x03.1e100.net: icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=18.3 ms
^C
--- www.google.pt ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 18.342/18.970/19.599/0.643 ms
greg@mycomputer:~$ ping www.google.pt
PING www.google.pt (216.58.192.227) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ord30s26-in-f3.1e100.net (216.58.192.227): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=19.0 ms
64 bytes from ord30s26-in-f3.1e100.net (216.58.192.227): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=18.3 ms
```